# SQL find quorum result from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a database table with football scores and multiple entries (from different sources) for each football match.

I need to select the current score using some sort of quorum mechanism, so that if the majority of sources agree on a score then that is the result, and if there is a tie, pick the score from a specific source (say, the score from ScoreProviderID 1).

The SCORES table looks something like this:

```
ID  ScoreProviderID  MatchID  HomeScore  AwayScore
 1                1        1          1          1
 2                2        1          2          1       
 3                3        1          2          1 
 4                4        1          1          1 
 5                5        1          2          1
```

Querying against this should yield a score of 2:1 (or 2 in a query for HomeScore).

I've gotten as far as this query:

```
SELECT HomeScore, COUNT(ID) AS Votes
FROM scores
GROUP BY HomeScore, MatchID
HAVING MatchID = 1
```

Which yields me a result like this:

```
HomeScore   Votes
----------- -----------
2           3
1           2
```

In summary, how can I query to retrieve either the top voted score, or in case of a tie, the score from a specific provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by slightly modifying your aggregation query.  Use an `order by` to order the results by the number of votes.  Then -- for the case where there are ties -- add an additional order by key to handle preferences among score providers:

```
SELECT TOP 1 HomeScore, COUNT(ID) AS Votes
FROM scores
WHERE MatchId = 1
GROUP BY HomeScore
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ScoreProviderID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC;
```

Note that I switched the `HAVING` clause to a `WHERE` clause, because the `WHERE` is more efficient.